# Is $(\mathbb R^d/\mathbb Z^d,+)$, $d>2$, isomorphic to some group of an algebraic surface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-theory

It is a well-known fact that for points of a cubic curve over $\mathbb{RP}^2$ we can define a group $(G_{\mathbb{RP}^2},+)$ using Cayley–Bacharach theorem. 
See [Wiki: The group law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law).

Another fact from complex analysis states that if consider points of a cubic curve over $\mathbb{CP}^2$ we also can define a group $(G_{\mathbb{CP}^2},+)$ such that it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2,+)$ (torus). 
For details see [Wiki: Elliptic curves over the complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Elliptic_curves_over_the_complex_numbers)

My question is the following. Is it possible to define groups (defined on tori) $(\mathbb R^d/\mathbb Z^d,+)$ as groups for some algebraic curves and surfaces?

My main interest in geometric interpretation first of all, see my comment below.

Comment: Yes, these are called abelian varieties. If you search, you will find a lot of material on this topic.

Comment: What is the meaning of "for some algebraic curves and surfaces"?

Comment: My main interest is the following. Is it possible that we have operation "plus" for an algabraic curve similar to operation "plus" for an elliptic curve. Let me illustrate. For the elliptic curve first of all we define one point as 0 then we take any two points (a and b) draw line through them find intersection point with the curbic curve and then draw line though the new point and 0, and intersection point of the last line and our cubic curve is sum of our original points a and b. I need something in this spirit for algebraic surfaces.
But I also am curious in facts of any nature.

Comment: Donu, do abelian varieties live in the same spirit as I describe above?

Comment: An abelian variety is a smooth projective variety with a group law compatible with the variety structure. Over $\mathbb{C}$, it is necessarily a torus. It is hard to say much more in comment box, but sounds like this is what you want.

Comment: Donu, I got this. But "in the same spirit" means "more or less simple geometric interpretation".